# Getting an unintended infinite while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

Given an integer. The task is to remove some digits and re-order the digits (if necessary) so that the resulting integer would be the maximum possible integer that is divisible by 3.

My algorithm is:

> 1. If the number is itself divisible by 3 then just print the digits in descending order.
> 2. If the number is 1 modulo 3 then remove one the smallest digit in the integer that is also 1 modulo 3 then just print the digits in descending order. If there is no such a digit then remove two smallest digits that are 2 modulo 3 then just print the digits in descending order.
> 3. If the number is 2 modulo 3 then similar to the case 2 above.

```
n = 223
s = str(n)

if n % 3 == 0:
    n = "".join(sorted(str(n), reverse=True))

if n % 3 == 1:
    n = "".join(sorted(str(n)))
    count = 0
    for char in s:
        if int(char) % 3 == 1:
            s = s.replace(char, '', 1)
            count+=1
    if count != 0:
        n = "".join(sorted(s, reverse=True))
        print(n)
    else:
        count2 = 0
        while count2 <= 2:
            print('l')
            for char in s:
                if int(char) % 3 == 2:
                    s = s.replace(char, '', 1)
                    count2+=1
        n = "".join(sorted(s, reverse=True))
        print(n)
```

Note that I haven't written the part of the code for Case 3. I was just checking for `n=223` which is in Case 2.

I am not an advanced coder yet, so some optimization (if possible) would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your loop never exits if the `if int(char) % 3 == 2` does not trigger twice.

Comment: Maybe the line `count2+=1` should be below `for` loop and not `if` condition ?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi but doesn't `n=223` have two occurrences of `2`?

Comment: @AlexandreB. but `count2` was intended to count that exactly 2 elements were removed. So I included that operation every time when any such `char` was removed...

Comment: I had a typo. Since the check is `while count2 <=  2`, count2 must be incremented thrice. 2 is still less *or equal* to 2.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks, I now got around the infinite loop!